# How to add L prefix to MACRO

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have

```
#define STRING "string"
```

I want to add L prefix to STRING macro later in my code (I can't do it in definition). How to do it?

Comment: A macro works on textual substitution, and is a compile-time mechanism. You cannot change it at run-time as and when you please.

Comment: You know. Maybe it isn't a duplicate. What do you mean **exactly** by *"add L prefix"*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define CONCATENATE(e1, e2) e1 ## e2
#define PREFIX_L(s) CONCATENATE(L, s)

#define STRING "string"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ls\n", PREFIX_L(STRING));
}
```

These standard C pre-processor's concatenation capabilities are also covered by the documentation coming with GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Comment: That is no a gcc feature, but standard.

Comment: @Olaf: I know, but the page is referring the GCC docs ... :}

Comment: @Olaf: You didn't downvote because of this, did you? |-)

Comment: Erm, to my ashame, the DV was in error and  cannot reconstruct why I actually did. Removed (had to edit a bit). Really sorry for that! Just please make clear this is not just gcc in the text!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#define STRING(x) x"string"

char * l_pString = STRING("");
wchar_t * l_pWideString = STRING(L);
```

Comment: This isn't built' properly. http://ideone.com/xIn2Br
You can't omit a macro parameter.

Comment: Adding up to @StoryTeller just pass `""` in the 1st case.